# When I start the application, the database drops

Tags: c#, database, linq

I'm working on a small Information System Application. I'm making it with windows forms and Service-based Database. It's almost done but when I execute the application a very odd problem appears. I make a stored procedure for inserting data in db tables and when i execute it manually it all works fine, but when I start the program and execute the procedure through button click something wrong is happened. At first sight the program is working fine and the procedure is executing well, but the data is not stored in the db. Here is my code:

UserData.cs

```
 public static bool AddStudent(Student std)
    {
        UserDataClassesDataContext dc = new UserDataClassesDataContext();
        try
        {
            dc.AddNewStudent(std.FirstName, std.SecondName, std.LastName, std.Faculty, std.Specialty, std.OKS,
                std.StudentStatus, std.FacNumber, std.Course, std.Potok, std.Group);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

StudentValidation.cs

```
public bool InsertStudent(Student std)
    {
        return UserData.AddStudent(std);
    }
```

MainForm.cs buttonClick event

```
private void insertStudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
        student.SecondName = tbSecondName.Text;
        student.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
        student.Faculty = tbFacultyName.Text;
        student.Specialty = tbSpecialty.Text;
        student.FacNumber = tbFacNumber.Text;
        student.OKS = (short)cbOKS.SelectedIndex;
        student.StudentStatus = (short)cbStudentStatus.SelectedIndex;
        student.Course = (short)numCourse.Value;
        student.Potok = tbFlow.Text;
        student.Group = tbGroup.Text;
        if (sv.InsertStudent(student) && sv.InsertUser(student))
            MessageBox.Show("The student is added successfully!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("A problem occurs while trying to add the student!");
    }
```

I think that the db is somehow disconnected when I start my application, but I don't know why.

Comment: Sounds like your database is recreated at start-time. How is your database deployed? And is it deployed at start-time?

Comment: what you have wrote in the function 'SubmitChanges()'

Comment: You seem to be catching your exceptions and ignoring them. Do you get any exceptions? If so, what do they say?

Comment: No i don't get any exceptions, it all goes fine. UserData is the class where I select and insert the data in my db. @Pandian - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx

Comment: If your database is included in your solution, than it could be `copy always` is set to `true` in your database properties, which would mean the database get's overwritten with every build.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this method:

db.students.InsertOnSubmit(std);

Consult this link for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx